# Search for complete bipartite subgraph of graph

Tags: graphs

What is the time complexity of the best-known algorithm to search for the largest complete bipartite subgraph (not induced subgraph, since not all edges have to be considered) in a given graph?

A complete bipartite graph $G = (V, E)$ can be partitioned into two subsets $V_1$ and $V_2$ such that each vertex of $V_1$ is connected to each vertex of $V_2$, but no edges exist between the nodes within both subsets.

The largest bipartite graph maximizes $|V_1|$ x $|V_2|$. I don't need them all, one is enough.

Actually, I am just looking for a source that says it is NP-complete to justify my usage of an approximation algorithm

Comment: Have you tried reducing from CLIQUE?  How do you measure the size of a bipartite graph?

Comment: [Find all complete sub-graphs within a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801138/find-all-complete-sub-graphs-within-a-graph) is NP-complete, but that's not quite what you asked for.

Comment: Complete bipartite subgraph is called "biclique".

Comment: I thought you are referring to the maximum edge biclique problem, which is NP-hard, but HEKTO points out that is for induced subgraphs, and you are asking about non-induced subgraphs, so it isn't relevant.  For induced subgraphs, see following paper:

René Peeters. "[The maximum edge biclique problem is NP-complete](https://pure.uvt.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/535705/789.pdf)." Discrete Applied Mathematics 131.3 (2003): 651-654.